# How to use Wireshark to capture traffic coming from VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, wireshark, macos-big-sur, diameter-protocol

I have installed [Seagull](http://gull.sourceforge.net/doc/diameter.html) to create client traffic simulation of diameter base protocol. I installed it on VMWare running Fedora Server since I found difficulty during my installation on my MacOS laptop but there are many tutorials how to install it on Linux.

I have Wireshark installed directly on the laptop machine. But my problem is I could not capture with Wireshark the traffic coming from VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. In the Wireshark check that you chose the correct network interface to listen to. (you can choose it with ctrl+k)
2. If you see traffic but not Diameter traffic, could be your Seagull traffic is not sending anything.

If you installed Fedora I suggest to use "tcpdump" command. It do the same as Wireshark but from Linux command line. It will give you a .cap file that you can examine.

If you dont see any Diameter traffic on the tcpdump file then the problem is in your Seagull. If you see Diameter traffic the problem is in your Wireshark configuration.